# programmatically alter kde file associations

Tags: scripting, kde, kde4, file-opening

**Problem:**

In kde I want to remove a particular file association from every file type

**Details:**

I wanted to try out clamTk as a companion to clamAv. It didn't suit my needs so I uninstalled the package. However, it had created an association with every file type on my system, which was not undone when I removed the package. I have looked in (user file) mimeapps.list and (system file) mimeinfo.cache hoping that it would be as simple as parsing these files to clean things up, but the associations are evidently more involved than that. Every file I click on in kde is set to scan via clamTk (which isn't there anymore anyway), and manually deleting every entry in Kde "System Settings" will be laborious.

Does anyone know an effective way to get at the file association configuration data?

```
Distro: Centos 6.2 (Final)
Kde:    4.3.4
```

**Update:** Wed, Feb 25

In reply to the comments others have made, on Centos (customized REL) the package manager is yum. The remove/erase switch for yum evidently does not "undo" this kind change, it just keeps dependencies correctly configured. So, it would appear, I am left to deal with cleaning up the file associations it made myself.

As for my definition of effective - some programmatic, non manual way (bash, sed, awk, c, etc) to automately spin through each association and remove the offending entry. The problem is, I don't know what to spin through. Does Kde keep this info in a file? files? sqlite db? How exactly does it make the relationship between the file type and the app to open it? Gnome is right up front with where they keep that info. Kde? Not so much. Exactly where they keep it, and ***how*** they keep it, is currently very elusive.

Comment: Did you remove the package, or purge? Also, KDE is a desktop environment, your packages are handled the same as they would be in any other desktop environment AFAIK.

Comment: I don't know an effective way, maybe someone else does. How do you define effective?